# Flow : destructuring. Missing annotation in React/Preact

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, static-typing, preact

Just getting started with Flow but can't seem to understand what it wants me to do with adding types for destructuring objects like i.e. props

i.e.

```
render({ count }, { displayHelp }) {
```

Throws an error like

```
 16:   render({ count }, { displayHelp }) {
              ^^^^^^^^^ destructuring. Missing annotation
```

and when I add annotation it still complains

```
 17:   render({ count: number }, { displayHelp }) {
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ destructuring. Missing annotation
```

I am obviously missing something very simple here if anybody could point out ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with doing `{ count: number }` is that this clashes with ES6 syntax for [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), where you can use `{ a: b } = c` in order to take the value with key `a` from `c` and have it be named `b`, ie:

```
const c = { a: 1 }
const { a: b } = c
//b is now a constant with value 1
```

There isn't really a good workaround for this in Flow right now, but this seems to work (although it is ugly):

```
render({...}: { count: number }, { displayHelp }) {
```

The best way right now seems to be to create a custom `type` which captures your props:

```
type propsForThisComponent = {
  propA: someType
  propB: anotherType
  ...
}
```

and then do:

```
render(props: propsForThisComponent) {
```

This typechecks, although it forces you to access all your props as `props.propName`.

Comment: I just tried this and I get a syntax error. Are you sure that works?

Comment: Nope, that was a mistake. It's actually a proposed feature. I'm looking for an actual way to get this to work right now and I'll edit as soon as I know a good one.

Comment: Ok I gotcha, I should have spotted the ES6 conflict. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
render({count}: {count: number}, {displayHelp}: {displayHelp: boolean}) { ...
```

Unfortunately I do not believe there is a more concise way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
type Props = {
    counter?: number
};

const Component = ({counter}: Props) => (
    <div className="App">
        {counter}
    </div>
);
```